# LASSO: k-fold Cross Validation of AR(p)-process

Tags: time-series, forecasting, cross-validation, lasso, autoregressive

To improve my intuition on shrinkage models, I want to "recode" the lasso by myself. However, I'm at the point, where I have to program the k-fold Cross-Validation. At my future application of the algorithm I will use time series models, especially (V)AR(p). Because of the time-ordering, the random k-fold- Validation" should cause into problems, right ? Regarding to that I've two questoins:

1) How the glmnet package is dealing with the cv of AR models

2) Do you know a way some sources, that show me how I can deal with it ?

I found this in the blog of [hyndman](https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/tscv/)

Comment: As far as I know, the glmnet package doesn't deal with AR models at all (neither "AR" nor "time series" are mentioned in the documentation).

Answer (score 1):

You need to use expanding window or rolling window, consider below example:

Lets say, you have a data-set of 100 obervations and you need at least 10 observations to fit a model, and you are estimating an AR(1) model. Then your algorithm will look like this:

```
FEATURES = X = [y_1, y_2, y_3, ...., y_99]

TARGET = Y = [y_2, y_3, y_4, ...., y_100]

CV_SCORES = []

FOR n in [10, 99) DO:

    train_X = [y_1, y_2, ..., y_n]

    train_Y = [y_2, y_3, ..., y_{n+1}]

    test_X = [y_{n+1}]

    test_Y = [y_{n+2}]

    fit your model to (train_X, train_Y)

    predict with test_X

    calculate the score with prediction and test_Y

    append the score to CV_SCORES
END
```

The methodology above is expanding window and it is time-series version of leave-one-out cross validation.

Comment: Although it is definitely valid and standard to do so, you actually do not *need* to use expanding or rolling windows; regular K-fold cross validation is valid for AR models under certain conditions.  Bergmeir, Hyndman and Koo (2015) shows this (it is linked in the blog post in the question).

Comment: I was not aware of this paper thank you so much. I gave AR as an example, as far as I understand from the paper, if the correct process is not AR and the error terms are correlated, you still carry the risk of overfitting. Thus I would still use expanding or rolling window since that methodology is more close to how the model works in production, and it is not dependent on the model specification.